# Unmodifiable music file tags

Tags: linux, ubuntu, music, tags

I have some music files (.mp3 and .flac) which have unmodifiable tags: After I change the tags, they revert to their original values automatically. It's not related to access permissions (using Linux) as in a same directory, with the same permissions, some files have modifiable tags and other not.
Is there such a thing as "protected" or "unmodifiable" tags? Are there solutions to force modification ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether those files have several sets of tags (ID3v1, ID3v2, APE...) maybe you're editing ID3v1/ID3v2 and leaving APE tags intact, which might be the ones being read by your player.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I tried using another tag editor (easytag), and I succeeded in changing the tags on rhythmbox.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no such thing as an 'unmodifiable tag' (unless the file is set to 'read only'), however, this situation sometimes arises when a tag is corrupted and/or written in a slightly non-standard manner that another application doesn't recognize.

In general when this happens, you can try using another tagging app, or more universally, use an application to remove the tag entirely, and then recreate it.

e.g. in MediaMonkey, Tools > Advanced Tag Management > Clean ID3 tags